# HTML page to PDF (angular js and d3 charts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, node.js

I have html page which may contains multiple tables and d3 charts, i want to export whole page to pdf, is there way to do it using angularjs or by javascript,jquery.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Is PhantomJS a possibility? It can render your page to a PDF.

Comment: @thriqon, Client would require PhantomJs binary, so this is not convenient solution.

Comment: Am perhaps a bit late to the game here, but @thriqon's idea doesn't necessarily require the client to have PhantomJS - it could sit on the backend, a webservice hooked up to it receives the request to turn the users current page into a PDF (which it does by navigating to and then returning the PDF). Whether that level of complexity is justified would depend on a bunch of factors (eg how cachable the content is, time to re-generate the charts etc etc)

Answer (score 2):

Try this to use jsPDF (http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/). I think it can help.

Answer (score 1):

try this http://www.fpdf.org/ it's a php class that turns your html to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Kendo](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/drawing-dom#getting-started) , setting an "id", in the container that you want to export, and then use the following code:

```
kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#exportthis"), {
       paperSize: "letter",
        margin: "0.5cm",
        scale: 0.5
   }).then(function(group) {
     kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "Converted PDF.pdf");
   });
```

in your view you have to set the id like in this example:

```
<div id="exportthis" class="...">
  ... more HTML code here...
</div>
```

then a button where we can call the function, and its ready to go.

I use this when i don't want an image on the pdf, like jspdf/pdfmake.js that use canvas.